What book should I read to learn about the magnetocaloric effect
I am trying to study the magnetocaloric effect for a project but I can't find any good resources that deeply talk about it.
Could you make any good recommandation to learn the basics about this effect and how it work in different materials.
It would be better if it is a book that you can buy but I am open to anything. I already took some electromagnetism and therodynamics courses so I am confortable with these two subjects but I am not 100% of an expert. I am searching for a introductive book on the link between thermodynamics and electromagnetics that focuses on the material aspect (I am currently in college studying material engineering). I would prefer it to have an intuitive approach to the effect before diving into the maths.

https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/133626
Buschow en De Boer, 'Physics of Magnetism and Magnetic Materials' has 3 pages on it.
Sheahen, Introduction to High-Temperature Superconductivity.
